# How can I import a key from my desktop to the cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, key-pair

Very new to using cloudformation and am having trouble figuring out the syntax for importing a key into the creation of the instance. Sorry if the formatting for this post is off. Lets say I have a key called MyKey.pem saved onto my desktop. How would I go about importing and applying the key to the instance I am creating in the template? Also, if someone could also inform me on the process of actually generating a new key within the template, and applying that, I would appreciate that as well. Here is the code I am creating the instance with.

Ec2Instance1:

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance

Properties:

  InstanceType: t2.micro

  ImageId: ami-07dcc3822b6f2bdbe

  KeyName: MyKey.pem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is **no direct way** in CloudFormation (CFN) to do it. The easiest way is to import the key using AWS console or CLI and then reference it by name in your templates.

But if you really want to do it through (CFN) you would have to use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be in the form of a lambda function which would use **AWS SDK** to create the key. The private key could come from SSM parameter store for instance where you would upload your key or [AWS::SecretsManager::Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html#cfn-secretsmanager-secret-secretstring).

**Update**
For example, if your key pair is called `MyKeyPair`, then in CFN you would use:

```
  MyEC2Instance: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
      ImageId: "ami-79fd7eee"
      KeyName: MyKeyPair
```

Comment: That is unfortunate. Could you explain to me the syntax of how I would import using the console? And then once it is imported, how I would go about referencing it in the template?

Comment: @edifarnecio The import procedure is explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws). Then in CloudFormation you reference it by using name of the key you created in the console.

Comment: @edifarnecio I updated an answer with example.